# Characteristic polynomial of companion matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-polynomial, companion-matrices

I have a matrix in companion form,

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}  0 & \cdots & 0& -a_{0} \\  1 & \cdots & 0 & -a_{1}\\ \vdots &\ddots & \vdots &\vdots \\ 0 &\cdots & 1 & -a_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}$$

where $A \in M_{n}$. I want to prove by induction that the characteristic polynomial is

$$p_{A}=t^{n}+a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+\cdots +a_{0}$$

The part that is confusing me is if we assume this hold for $A_{1}\in M_{n-1}$ how do we transform, or "add" to $A_{1}$ to get the n by n matrix $A\in M_{n}$? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate of the linked question--that one asks about the minimal polynomial, and this question doesn't--and @BillCook's helpful answer to this question here isn't given at the linked question.  (Even if it's implicit in something written there it's not spelled out as in Bill Cook's answer.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As suggested in the comment above, expand along the first row:

$$\mathrm{det}(tI_n-A) = \mathrm{det} \begin{pmatrix}  t &  0 & \cdots & 0 & a_0 \\
                                         -1 &  t & \cdots & 0 & a_1 \\
                                       \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
                                          0 &  0 & \cdots & -1 & t+a_{n-1} \end{pmatrix} = $$

$$ t \cdot \mathrm{det} \; \begin{pmatrix} t &  0 & \cdots & 0 & a_1 \\
                   -1 &  t & \cdots & 0 & a_2 \\
                  \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
                    0 &  0 & \cdots & -1 & t+a_{n-1} \end{pmatrix} +
   (-1)^{1+n} a_0 \cdot \mathrm{det} \begin{pmatrix} -1 &  t & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
                               0 & -1 & t & \cdots & 0 \\
                  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
                    0 &  0 & \cdots & 0 & -1 & \end{pmatrix} $$

By induction we can replace the determinant on the left by $a_1+a_2t+\cdots+a_{n-1}t^{n-2}+t^{n-1}$ and the second matrix's determinant is the product of its diagonals (since it's upper-triangular). The product of the diagonals is $(-1)^{n-1}$. Therefore, the determinant is $t(a_1+a_2t+\cdots+a_{n-1}t^{n-2}+t^{n-1})+(-1)^{n+1}(-1)^{n-1}a_0$. Which simplifies to $a_0+a_1t+\cdots+a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+t^n$.

[When writing this up, don't forget the base case for the induction.]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation

Comment: Can you explain why you were able to go from line 1 to line 2 (which properties of the determinant).

Comment: As stated, I expanded along the first row. This is the standard Laplace expansion. Since all but 2 entries in the first row are zero, the expansion only has 2 nonzero terms.